# Java + Selenise execute java script to send api request

Tags: javascript, java, api, selenium

I Use Java + Selenium to build a tests. I need to use a js function in my code to send API request to refresh a data in active google chrome vindow. I tryed to use custom selenium function *executeJavaScript* to do this, but as a result  I got nothing (null or size 0 in diferent requests)

code GET:

```
      executeJavaScript( "return (function (){ var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); " +
            "  xmlHttp.open( 'GET', 'http://myserver.url', false );" +
            "  xmlHttp.send( null ); " +
            "  return xmlHttp.responseText;})" );
```

code POST:

```
executeJavaScript("return (function (theUrl){  " +
    " var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
            "  xmlHttp.open( 'POST', theUrl, false );" +
            "  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('token', token); " +
            "  xmlHttp.send( null ); " +
            "  return xmlHttp.responseText;})", "http://myserver.url", "myToken");
```

May by my main idea to refresh data in pafe using API request is not a correct?

Comment: you have an anonymous function that returns something... but you never call it, you just return it. (or maybe I'm not understanding something here?)

Comment: Use executeAsyncScript instead